# Producer-consumer algorithm to use full buffer

Tags: c, algorithm, producer-consumer

I was reading Galvin OS book about producer consumer problem and came through this piece of code.

**Global definitions**

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
typedef struct {
    . . .
} item;

int in  = 0;
int out = 0;
```

**Producer**

```
while (((in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE) == out)
    ; /* do nothing */
buffer[in] = next_produced;
in = (in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE ;
```

**Consumer**

```
while (in == out)
    ; /* do nothing */
next_consumed = buffer[out];
out = (out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
```

Now this is what Galvin book says:

> This scheme allows at most BUFFER_SIZE − 1 items in the buffer at the
>   same time. We leave it as an exercise for you to provide a solution in which
>   BUFFER_SIZE items can be in the buffer at the same time.

This is what I came up with. Is this correct?

**Producer**

```
buffer[in] = next_produced;  //JUST MOVED THIS LINE!
while (((in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE ) == out)
    ; /* do nothing */
in = (in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
```

**Consumer**

```
while (in == out)
    ; /* do nothing */
next_consumed = buffer[out];
out = (out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
```

I think this solves, but is this correct? Any other better solution possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did your test run show you? SO is no site for code review but for solving _specific_ problems.

Comment: It's not a code error. It's a question about the logic and the algorithm! Read about producer-consumer problem!

Comment: I do know the producer & consumer problem. But you do not provide a specific problem. Did you test it? Does your producer identify empty and full buffer correctly and doesn't overwrite existing entries? Does your consumer recognize empty buffer correctly and read the values in correct order? If your test fails, we can solve a **specific** problem. Or you name a specific doubt where you think you are wrong.

Comment: BTW: Claiming someon doesn't know enough about the topic and first should read a bit isn't the best idea in most cases. Especially when it is obvious that you didn't bother to read the guidelines for this site. Please first read [The tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The question is OK. It is an algorithm, so it should not be complete...

Comment: @MartinJames IMO you comment does not help much. He is new on SO, be kind, guys...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original piece of code, when `in == out` it could mean the buffer is empty OR full. So to avoid such an ambiguity, the original code do not allow buffer to full, always leaving at least one empty item.

I am not sure you are solving this problem with your change: you will be able to put BUFFER_SIZE items, but you will not be able to consume them. So, literally you solved it, but it will not function properly.

Basically, to solve this problem, you should have an extra piece of information, so you can distinct between an empty buffer and full. There are a variety solutions for that, the most obvious is to add an extra flag.

The most elegant IMO is to use `in` and `out` counters as is, wrapping them only to access the buffer, so:

- when `in == out` -- the buffer is empty
- when `abs(in - out) == BUFFER_SIZE` -- the buffer is full
- to access the buffer we should use `buffer[in % BUFFER_SIZE]` or `buffer[out % BUFFER_SIZE]`

We leave it as an exercise for you to provide a complete solution ;)

Comment: your kindness will take you  a long way in life.. and yeah tc